# How to remove rectangle around label

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, style

I am using QGIS 3.16.10 Hannover. Whenever I activate a label it also shows a lot of rectangles around the label. Does any one know how to remove them?

[image]

Comment: Try the following: In the label settings, got to the tab `Placement` and deactivate `Repeating labels`. Go to the Tab `Background` and disable `Draw background`.

Answer (score 6):

These rectangle are probably "candidate position" (ie. emplacement the labelling engine consider while placing label, the placement engine choose the best candidate relative to your setting to avoid overlap).

To make then disappear you should go to the Placement engine setting (click on the cogwheel next to the label selector)

[image]

Then deselect the "Show candidates (for debugging)" checkbox

[image]

Comment: Fantastic that works. Thank you very much :-).